# How can I move the contents of a bootstrap navbar to the middle?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to make a simple navbar and I want the content of the navbar like "home" and "contact" to be shifted to the right a bit so that it works for mobile users too. This is what my navbar looks like and the red line I drew represents where I want the start of "Test" to be.
[image]

I'm not sure how to move "Test Home Contact Us" to the start of that red line. I tried putting `style="left:200px"` inside each of the texts' `<a>...</a>` section, but it didn't work. I'm using a bootstrap navbar so I basically just copy and pasted a navbar from bootstrap and here's the code for it:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('home_page') }}"><b>Test</b></a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNav"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home_page') }}"
              >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="market">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely looking for `style="padding-left: 200px;"` instead of `left`.

Comment: Would you happen to know a way on how I can make it responsive and incorporate percentages? Preferably to 67% because that's how much % the black strip in the middle takes up. Thanks regardless

Comment: Percentages work fine, just replace the `200px` with `10%` or the like. You can make it responsive in a CSS stylesheet (using media queries), but i'm not aware of any bootstrap-specific-way (with their predefined classes) to really do a padding this large. It's likely you have to rethink the overall layout a bit, from a higher level pov. The flexboxes (of which navbar is one implementation, but bootstrap has other containers) have support for many different ways of accomplishing the result you're likely after.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding a `container` div next to `<nav>` tag would help.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('home_page') }}"><b>Test</b></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home_page') }}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="market">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#containers

Answer (score 1):

You have to give `padding-left` to entire `nav`tag. For exapmle:

```
nav {
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```